# How does a HTTP Reverse Proxy work

Tags: http, tcp, proxy, subdomain, reverse-proxy

I saw a website that offers HTTP Reverse proxy and TCP Reverse Proxy, I know what TCP Reverse Proxy is, but I have no clue what the difference is between HTTP & TCP Reverse proxy.

Try to explain it to someone that would like to buy it, because i want to know how it works. Those website's that offers it usually says "1 Protected Domain".

Comment: I'd imagine that a tcp reverse proxy is appliction protocol agnostic, while HTTP proxy is application protocol aware. http://serverfault.com/questions/611272/haproxy-http-vs-tcp  do you need routing based on HTTP specific features?  It looks like one way nginx does sticky sessions is by dropping a cookie, in which case I think it may need to be HTTP proxy? https://www.nginx.com/products/session-persistence/

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to a simple TCP reverse proxy a HTTP proxy can choose the target HTTP server based on the content of the HTTP request, i.e. based on the target host name (Host header), the path, Cookies, the User-Agent etc. It can also include additional headers like X-Forwarded-For to include the clients original IP address.